# How can I replace all occurrences of the division sign with a slash in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I would like to replace all division signs and multiplication signs in a string with the characters `/` and `*`. How can I do that? I already tried it with this method but it does not work.

```
public static String formatString(String string) {
    String result = string;
    result = string.replaceAll("\\\u00F7", "/"); 
    result = string.replaceAll("\\\u00D7", "*"); 
    return result;
}
```

And this is were I got the unicode for the division and multiplication signs from:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f7/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00d7/index.htm

Comment: Code would be clearer if you used '×' and '÷', use 'compose xx' for '×', and 'compose -:' for '÷'. Gnu/Linux has this build it, just configure it. MS-Windows has a 3rd party program (that I use at work).

Comment: @richard If OP used the Unicode chars directly, he wouldn't have written this question :)

Comment: Yes so good advice then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't work because of the way regex's work.

`"\\\u00F7"` gets passed into the regex parser as `\÷`.
The parser then tries to find the correct escape sequence for that, but there is none. The solution is to remove two of the `\`s:

```
public static String formatString(String string) {
    String result = string;
    result = result.replace("\u00F7", "/"); 
    result = result.replace("\u00D7", "*"); 
    return result;
}
```

Sample run: http://ideone.com/R8YJuC

Better than [`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) is to use [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28char,%20char%29):

```
public static String formatString(String string) {
    String result = string;
    result = result.replace('\u00F7', '/'); 
    result = result.replace('\u00D7', '*'); 
    return result;
}
```

It is best to avoid regex if it is unneeded.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String#replace`, not `String#replaceAll` (the latter is using regular expression syntax; method name is kind of a false friend):

```
result = string.replace("\u00F7", "/");
result = string.replace("\u00D7", "*");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in your code.  One is that you have an extra blackslash in your regular expression.  The other is that you are doing  the second replacement on the original string, and throwing away the result of the first replacement.  It doesn't matter whether you use `replace` or `replaceAll`, so long as you fix those first two bugs.

```
public static String formatString(String string) {
    String result = string.replaceAll("\u00F7", "/"); 
    result = result.replaceAll("\u00D7", "*"); 
    return result;
}
```